# How to lift easygui window above all windows in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, easygui

I've started using `easygui` instead of `tkinter` because its easy, but I've run into a little problem the following code when used in jupyter notebook launches a window but it will pop up behind the browser.

```
import easygui

easygui.filesavebox(default="hello.txt")
```

Is there any possible way to lift the windows to the top of all windows like in `tkinter`?

Comment: `easygui` also uses `tkinter`, and it's not quite possible doing that with `tkinter.filedialog` either. There's just not that feature included:( The only possible way is to somehow use `subprocess.call` to give focus to it.

Comment: okay so what does `tkinter`'s `lift()` method do?

Comment: doesn't work when the `root` is withdrawn (which is how `easygui` not show the white tkinter window). You can see that if you look at it's source code.